# SQL server query returns but function does not

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

In my `Java` based web project, I have made one `recursive` query as below which runs perfectly fine and returns list of `ids`.

```
WITH treeResult(id) AS 
    (SELECT pt.id FROM myschema.art_artwork_tree AS pt WHERE pt.id in 
      (select node_id from myschema.art_brand_user_mapping where emp_id = $1)
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT pa.id FROM treeResult AS p, myschema.art_artwork_tree AS pa 
     WHERE pa.parent_node = p.id and pa.site_id = $2) SELECT id FROM treeResult AS n
    );
```

Now, I want to use it in `JPQL` query. So, I have made `function` as below.

```
USE [darshandb]
GO

DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[testfunction]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[testfunction] (@empId INT,@siteId INT)
     RETURNS TABLE
     WITH SCHEMABINDING
     AS
     RETURN
     (
      WITH treeResult(id) AS 
        (SELECT pt.id FROM myschema.art_artwork_tree AS pt WHERE pt.id in 
          (select node_id from myschema.art_brand_user_mapping where emp_id = $1)
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT pa.id FROM treeResult AS p, myschema.art_artwork_tree AS pa 
         WHERE pa.parent_node = p.id and pa.site_id = $2) SELECT id FROM treeResult AS n
    );
GO
```

When I am trying to execute `function`, it does not return any value.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[testfunction] (4,3);
```

Please help me, what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the use of `$1` and `$2` in your function query. Just use the original parameter names in your table valued function.

So, replace $1 by @empId and $2 by @siteId in your user defined function.